# TCPDF page borders?

Tags: php, pdf, coding-style, tcpdf

I'm trying to achieve simple 1px solid red border around each page generated in TCPDF. Previously using other PDF scripts I was forced to draw a rectangle after doing some rough calculations with getting the page width and height and -20px (to allow for 10px indentation on each side). However I'm unsure how I can achieve a similar result with TCPDF.

Does anyone have any experience?

Answer (score 9):

Here you go (this will draw a black line of 15 points around the current page)

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetLineStyle( array( 'width' => 15, 'color' => array(0,0,0)));

$pdf->Line(0,0,$pdf->getPageWidth(),0); 
$pdf->Line($pdf->getPageWidth(),0,$pdf->getPageWidth(),$pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->Line(0,$pdf->getPageHeight(),$pdf->getPageWidth(),$pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->Line(0,0,0,$pdf->getPageHeight());
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Rect](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_Rect):

```
$pdf->SetLineStyle( array( 'width' => 15, 'color' => array(0,0,0)));
$pdf->Rect(0, 0, $pdf->getPageWidth(), $pdf->getPageHeight());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$pdf->SetLineStyle( array( 'width' => 15, 'color' => array(0,0,0)));
$pdf->Line(0,0,$pdf->getPageWidth(),0); 
$pdf->Line($pdf->getPageWidth(),0,$pdf->getPageWidth(),$pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->Line(0,$pdf->getPageHeight(),$pdf->getPageWidth(),$pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->Line(0,0,0,$pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->SetLineStyle( array( 'width' => 14, 'color' => array(255,255,255)));
$pdf->Line(0,0,$pdf->getPageWidth(),0); 
$pdf->Line($pdf->getPageWidth(),0,$pdf->getPageWidth(),$pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->Line(0,$pdf->getPageHeight(),$pdf->getPageWidth(),$pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->Line(0,0,0,$pdf->getPageHeight());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TCPDF [Line](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a89c0fac95da962719ba92b057df9c201) function and create four lines around each side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public function Header()
{
    $this->writeHTMLCell($w='', $h='', $x='', $y='', $this->header, $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='L', $autopadding=true);
    
    $this->SetLineStyle( array('width'=>0.40,'color'=> array(0,0,0)));
    
    $this->Line(5,5, $this->getPageWidth()-5,5);
    
    $this->Line($this->getPageWidth()-5,5, $this->getPageWidth()-5, $this->getPageHeight()-5);
    $this->Line(5, $this->getPageHeight()-5, $this->getPageWidth()-5, $this->getPageHeight()-5);
    $this->Line(5,5,5, $this->getPageHeight()-5);
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.